# Difference of using static between java and PHP?

Tags: java, php, static

In `Java` i read that, `static function` can access only `static function` or `static variable`. I was trying to find out the difference of using static in PHP and java.

1. Does the same is also in `PHP`?
2. Can we call `non-static function` inside the `static function`, in `PHP`?

Comment: You can call a non-static method from a static one in both PHP and Java -- you just need to provide the object on which to call it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we call non-static function inside the static function, in PHP?

**Yes but not adviced.** As `$this` keyword won't be available under static context. However, you can do that using the `static` / `self` keyword but that will result in a *Strict standards notice*

> Strict standards: Non-static method A::foo() should not be called
>   statically

<kbd>[Demonstration on Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AZTEPY)</kbd>

So better not do it !

Comment: `class A {
   public function foo()
   {
       print("<br/>foo A");
   }

   public static function bar()
   {
       static::foo();
   }
}`
is above is valid?

Comment: yes i also found the same as you. Thus use of static in PHP and Java is not same.

Comment: You will get a warning and you should not do that IMHO. You can see the demo.

Comment: In PHP you are getting warning and it will execute. But in java it will be compile time error. You can not do this. Thus not same in both PHP and Java

Comment: @Rahul, I agree to that, yeah I've seen that you will get a compile error, but PHP got no compiler right ? It's just an interpreted one. I will edit the answer.

Comment: agree with you. But there is difference between error and warning either it is through compiler or interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think it's the same.

BTW, EDIT for STATIC functions (didn't read correctly...)

For Java, a static variable will survive throughout the whole life when JVM is running or when class is unloaded using some techniques. That means, once the static variable is used, it will exist in memory.

PHP hasn't any memory. So, the variables, which is even declared as "static" or "Global", will be destroyed...

for the 2. Yes. If the instance of your class is rarely needed, you can have the static method create an instance, call the non-static method and return the value.

```
class Scope {
    public function mynonstatic() {
    }

    public static function mystatic() {
        $s = new Scope();
        return $s->mynonstatic();
    } }
```

Remember that a static method is really just a global function with reduced scope. They are useful, but are should not be created without good reason.

Source here : http://yiyujia.blogspot.ro/2010/09/static-variable-in-php-vs-static.html

Comment: I edited my answer because I thought the question talked about static variables... I don't erase my answer because it can brought some extra answers...

Comment: It is good that you made clear the difference in architecture (especially memory) but if you cited others [ http://yiyujia.blogspot.ro/2010/09/static-variable-in-php-vs-static.html ] please put a link to them so other can study the problem in detail

Answer (score 0):

First static is a keyword.
and it used before declaring a variable or a function name.

What is Static Variable in Java?
Static variable in Java is variable which belongs to the class and initialized only once at the start of the execution. It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance ). Static variables are initialized only once, at the start of the execution. These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables.

*A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
*A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.

```
    public class Demo{
   public static void main(String args[]){
     Student s1 = new Student();
     s1.showData();
     Student s2 = new Student();
     s2.showData();
     //Student.b++;
     //s1.showData();
  }
}

class Student {
int a; //initialized to zero
static int b; //initialized to zero only when class is loaded not for each object created.

  Student(){
   //Constructor incrementing static variable b
   b++;
  }

   public void showData(){
      System.out.println("Value of a = "+a);
      System.out.println("Value of b = "+b);
   }
//public static void increment(){
//a++;
//}

}
```

Static variable
It is a feature of PHP to delete the variable, once it completes its execution and memory is freed. Sometimes we need to store a variable even after completion of function execution. Therefore, another important feature of variable scoping is static variable. We use the static keyword before the variable to define a variable, and this variable is called as static variable.

Static variables exist only in a local function, but it does not free its memory after the program execution leaves the scope. Understand it with the help of an example:

```
   <?php  
    function static_var()  
    {  
        static $num1 = 3;       //static variable  
        $num2 = 6;          //Non-static variable  
        //increment in non-static variable  
        $num1++;  
        //increment in static variable  
        $num2++;  
        echo "Static: " .$num1 ."</br>";  
        echo "Non-static: " .$num2 ."</br>";  
    }  
      
//first function call  
    static_var();  
  
    //second function call  
    static_var();  
?>  
//Output:

Static: 4
Non-static: 7
Static: 5
Non-static: 7
```